# DSX: Cannot edit Jupyter notebook

Tags: data-science-experience

When creating a new notebook, dsx fails when trying to connect to the Spark instance with the following error message:

> Sorry, we could not start your service. Please contact support with
>   the following information: The service UUID could not be established.
>   Description: PUT /analytics/notebooks/reactivate?sparkService=&createTenant=true failed.

What can we do to resolve this?

Comment: could you try to remove/create a new Spark Service?

Comment: Is it your own Spark service, or did somebody else create it for you? In the latter case, ask the creator of the service to create the very first notebook for that service. The permission handling for this case will be fixed in a few days.

Comment: Creating a new Spark instance solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact support. There's no obvious link, but your DSX account is backed by a Bluemix account and an Apache Spark service in Bluemix, so you can use the Bluemix support channels.

In DSX, click on the logged-in symbol in the top right corner. In the menu that opens, select "Settings". In the Settings screen, there's a button "Manage Bluemix Account", and below that a link "Contact Support".
Alternatively, a click on "Manage Bluemix Account" will take you to the Bluemix console, where you can use the "Support" menu.